# Batch How to remove file extension stored in string %variable%?

Tags: batch-file

I got file named abcd.txt, i want to use string variable to rename the file to abcd_copy.txt. I have tried `ren`command, but it just give me abcd.txt_copy.txt
My approach is to remove .txt in %variable% and then use 
`ren abcd.txt %varialbe%"_copy.txt"` to rename the file. The problematic code is shown below:

```
set variable=abcd.txt
ren *.txt %variable%"_copy.txt"
```

Any suggestions?
TIA^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain that the extension are the last 4 characters (including the point), you can do:

```
%variable:~0,-4%
```

The -4 means that the last 4 digits will be truncated.
So, in your case, it will be:

```
ren *.txt "%variable:~0,-4%_copy.txt"
```

Comment: Down and dirty and solves the specific question asked.  The only risk (as pointed out) is that it assumes the length of the file extension.  If however the file was .html it wouldn't work.    I suggest using the builtin variable editing %~n and %~x to get filename and extension.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the FOR loop with Parameter substitution.  The FOR loop is also good if you have several files in a folder.

You want to use a combination of %~n and %~x.  %~n will return the FILENAME without the extension, and %~x will return the extension.

Example:

```
for %i in (*.txt) do echo Filename: %~ni Extension: %~xi
```

Your need appears to be:

```
set variable=abcd.txt
for %i in (%variable%) do ren %i %~ni_copy%~xi
```

which directly executes

> ren abcd.txt abcd_copy.txt

Keep in mind that you need double %% when used in a batch script.

from CMD prompt try:  "help for" and page down a bit.  You'll see lots of options

See this link for more detail including other args... 
http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

You might also find something useful here - it discusses string subs.
http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html

Comment: Your ans is great also, and thanks in advance for the detailed tutorials and suggestions on how to learn well in batch script programming.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
set variable=abcd.txt
for %%# in ("%variable%") do ren "%%~#" "%%~n#_copy%%~x#"
```